# Can a RHEL 6.4 DS sync with a CentOS 5.4 DS

Tags: centos, rhel, ldap, openldap

I have two CentOS 5.4 Directory Servers that sync information on a daily bases. I'm wanting to replace them with two RHEL 6.4 Directory Servers. Before the existing two are decommissioned all four need to be syncing on a daily basis until we are certain there aren't going to be any issues.

Essentially the RHEL DS and the CentOS DS directory servers are the same things so I'm betting that they can sync, but my main question is if a RHEL 6 DS can sync with a RHEL/CentOS 5 DS? Again I'm thinking they can because the database should be nearly the same for both, but I'm hoping someone knows for certain. If they can't natively sync I'm hoping find the best way to configure them so that they can.

My last issue is that the RHEL6 DS will have an additional schema (Samba). If the older DS doesn't have that schema will it just be left out when the servers sync?